# How can i achieve this custom Shape in android for a textview?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-shape, android-shapedrawable

How would I achieve a shape like below in Android, through an Android shape drawable:

[image]

Comment: I can't believe this question is so well received.. Usually questions like this gets downvoted because the lack of effort and info given by OP.

Comment: You're right, sorry, this was my first question and i was just testing the platform, I decided to erase it because I really had the answer, but someone had already commented, so I decided to simply accept their response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply create a custom shape and set it as background to your `TextView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#00ff00" />

    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="4dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="4dp" />

</shape>
```

You can acchieve the shadow by just setting the elevation attribute on your `TextView` (or wrap it in a `CardView` and set the elevation tehre if you are using an older version of Android)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a XML drawable file like the one provided below and then put `android:background="@drawable/my_bg.xml"` in your textview.

Example: my_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#EF4836"/>

    <stroke android:width="0dp"
        android:color="@android:color/transparent"
        />

    <padding android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        />

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="4dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="4dp" android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
</shape>
```